# Number of domains in vultr?

Tags: domain, vps

How many website domains can a Vultr account have? My understandin is Vultr accounts are like VPS in that you can have unlimited domains/websites?

Answer (score 1):

You do indeed have a VPS at vultr, so any limits on the number of domains you can host are not imposed by the vendor. Rather, you will need to consider hardware resource limits and application configuration limits to determine this number.

That said, in general, the **number** of domains isn't as important as the load that each domain produces.